# How to figure out exact reason why Regex is failing in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a Regex Pattern that i am using to match screen.
When i use it to test in Sublime Text, the same is working just fine.
but in Java execution, the code is failing

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(B+)?|(R+)?", "RRBRR"));//false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(B+)?|(R+)?", "RRRRR"));//true
```

The above code should be coming as true in both cases, whereas in java it is coming as false.

my basic requirement is to identify groups of unique character in sequence...

meaning if String is

```
RRRRBBBRRBBBRBBBRRR
```

Then it should identify as

```
RRRR BBB RR BBB R BBB RRR
```

Please help...Thanks in advance

Comment: The pattern is anchored in `matches()`, it is as if it were inside `^(?:...)$`.

Comment: what should i do...please help

Comment: Use `Matcher#find()`

Comment: See http://ideone.com/JTXcq0

Comment: Thanks...but i need to get the count of all the matches as well...is it possible in that...?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wonder ... why you don't write an answer?

Comment: I am very busy - I am putting kids to bed

Comment: For matching you can use :- `((B+)|(R+))+`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew...

Comment: I guess you know you can use a counter and increment it in the `while` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String value = "RRRRBBBRRBBBRBBBRRR";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("B+|R+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

The fact that the first expression returns false is due to the fact that you have a B in a middle of several R so you don't have an exact match since your regular expression expect only Rs or Bs

Comment: Thanks this is the exact Regex that i needed

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

matches adds an implicit ^ at the start & $ at the end which means substring matches wont work. find() will look for substring.

Matcher is best suited for this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String regex = "(B+)?|(R+)?";
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher("RRBRR");
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
        int count = 0;
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Count:"+count);

    }
```